# Как создать продвинутую карту здания? Со

Tags: html, yandex-maps-api

Итак, начнем с простого плана.

1. Приходишь в здание и сканируешь QR-код.
2. Тебя перекидывает на сайт.
3. Ты выбираешь этаж на котором находишься.
4. Далее, вводишь номер кабинета в который тебе нужно.
5. GPS навигатор указывает куда тебе нужно идти.
   Как это просто звучит. Но всё, что я могу - это создать сайт и разместить его на бесплатном хостинге. Я прошу элементарных подсказок: с чего начать, как нарисовать карту здания, как разместить ее на сайте, как оформить: GPS, поиск, навигатор. Вопросов много, и я надеюсь на скорые ответы. Я обратился к этому сайту, так как информация в интернете очень расплывчива и никто не говорит на понятном мне, языке.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Не надейтесь на GPS внутри здания. Он там (под крышей) работать чисто физически неспособен. В лучшем случае по Wi-Fi-точкам что-то получится определять, но точность там обычно никакая для навигации пешехода.

А в целом создать карту на базе **[API Яндекс Карт](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi)** вполне реально. Для этого следует добавить на карту [пользовательские слои](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_map). В сети можно найти сторонние примеры реализации, например вот [весьма недурной экземпляр](https://%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA.%D1%80%D1%84/skhema-trk/). Скрипт, добавляющий эту карту начинается с 226-й строки исходного кода страницы, может поможет понять принцип.

Comment: Спасибо, чувак. Где карту такую нарисовать?

Comment: В каком смысле "где"? Если есть сайт. Публичную карту вы добавляете скриптом самостоятельно. Если с кодом всё более-менее понятно, основная задача - нарисовать саму схему ТЦ в любом удобном фоторедакторе и разбить на слои и тайлы.

Comment: Извини за глупые вопросы. Я не знаю в каком приложении можно нарисовать [такую карту](https://фестивальангарск.рф/skhema-trk/).

Comment: Насколько понимаю, для такого нужен софт, умеющий в 3D моделировать. Подобное есть и среди бесплатного ПО. Можно тем же SketchUp воспользоваться (сборками тех времён, пока Гугл его Тримблу не продал и они были freeware). А вот какой софт будет удобней вам - пробуйте.